# Advanced boosting of angular digest loop

Tags: angularjs

I'm researching my options for boosting angular's digest loop.

I have a fairly complex app with tens of thousands active watchers at any given time.

As part of the functionality of the app I'm registering on scroll events (and handling them in an animation frame), so the digest is basically executed on each scroll, which results in an occasional drop in fps.

I've reduced the watchers count by one-time bindings and I'm now left with a few thousands watchers.

Currently I'm attempting to write a directive to suspend all watchers of out of viewport elements.

So I started playing with angular internals and came up with the following directive:

```
app.directive('ngSuspendable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var _watchersMap = {};
            var _suspended = true;
            suspendWatchersTree();

            function suspendWatchersTreeRecursive(currentScope, includeSiblings) {
                while (currentScope != null) {
                    if ((currentScope.$$watchers != null) &&
                        (currentScope.$$watchers.length > 0) &&
                        (typeof _watchersMap[currentScope.$id] == "undefined")) {
                        _watchersMap[currentScope.$id] = currentScope.$$watchers;
                        currentScope.$$watchers = [];
                    }

                    if (currentScope.$$childHead != null) {
                        suspendWatchersTreeRecursive(currentScope.$$childHead, true);
                    }

                    if (includeSiblings) {
                        currentScope = currentScope.$$nextSibling;
                    }

                    else {
                        currentScope = null;
                    }
                }
            }

            function unsuspendWatchersTreeRecursive(currentScope, includeSiblings) {
                while (currentScope != null) {
                    if ((typeof _watchersMap[currentScope.$id] != "undefined") &&
                        (_watchersMap[currentScope.$id].length > 0)) {
                        if ((currentScope.$$watchers != null) &&
                            (currentScope.$$watchers.length > 0)) {
                            currentScope.$$watchers = currentScope.$$watchers.concat(_watchersMap[currentScope.$id]);
                        }

                        else {
                            currentScope.$$watchers = _watchersMap[currentScope.$id];
                        }
                    }

                    if (currentScope.$$childHead != null) {
                        unsuspendWatchersTreeRecursive(currentScope.$$childHead, true);
                    }

                    if (includeSiblings) {
                        currentScope = currentScope.$$nextSibling;
                    }

                    else {
                        currentScope = null;
                    }
                }
            }

            function suspendWatchersTree() {
                suspendWatchersTreeRecursive(scope, false);
            }

            function unsuspendWatchersTree() {
                unsuspendWatchersTreeRecursive(scope, false);
            }

            scope.inView = function(evnt, model, htmlElementId, triggeringEvent, isInView, inViewPart) {
                if (!isInView) {
                    suspendWatchersTree();
                    _suspended = true;
                }

                if ((isInView) && (_suspended)) {
                    unsuspendWatchersTree();
                    _watchersMap = {};
                    _suspended = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Upon initialization this directive removes all watchers from current scope and all child scopes (not sure if it captures also isolated scopes).
Then, when the element is in view it adds back the watchers, and removes them when out of view.

I know that it doesn't necessarily captures all watchers, as some watchers might be added post linking, but that seems negligible, and they will be removed once the element comes in view and out of view again. If I could somehow hook to the watchers addition and add them to the map when suspsended that could be nice but I guess its not a must.

This seems to be working well but I'm not sure what are the caveats for such approach. I'm uncomfortable with playing around with angular internals and messing up things and reaching unstable conditions.

Any ideas and remarks will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is a [codereview.se]. Great site for asking about working code. Be sure to read their help center to make sure your question is on topic though.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the above code with the most recent changes.
Further testing showed it works fairly well, some watches might not be suspended at initialization but that's a price I can live with. It greatly enhanced my digest loop and boosted the app performance by removing unrequired watches for out of viewport elements.